# Street like tyres on smaller bike?

Tags: bicycles

Is it possible to get rolling resistance of best street tyres on smaller wheels say 20", 16" or way smaller like scooter or in-line wheels ?

Looking for best options for specials like [Streetstrider](https://www.streetstrider.com/), [A-Bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-bike), etc.

Answer (score 1):

For rolling resistance, you generally want a moderate tyre width. Very thin tyres have too high rolling resistance. I'd say 32mm - 35mm is most optimal, but the wider the tyre is, the harder it's to find good low rolling resistance tyres available. For example today you can by Continental GP5000 in 32mm width but not in 35mm width.

You also want high TPI in the casing. TPI means threads per inch. High rolling resistance tyres have 60 TPI (sometimes mistakenly marketed as 180 TPI due to there being three plies), low rolling resistance tyres have 110-120 TPI (sometimes mistakenly marketed as 330-360 TPI due to there being three plies).

The casing has to withstand high pressures. Don't buy anything that won't take at least 7 bar / 100 PSI. You also want to use these high pressures, and pump up the tire at least weekly because high-pressure tires leak air naturally very fast.

Also, you want absolutely minimal puncture protection. Generally, in normal conditions, every hour you save due to puncture protection (not having to patch punctures) causes you to lose 10-100 hours due to higher rolling resistance.

Furthermore, you want thin high quality rubber. Thicker rubber means longer tire lifetime (if of equivalent quality), but higher rolling resistance. Because the rubber has to be so thin, it has to be of high quality or else you'll wear the tyre to its casing in 500 kilometers.

The rubber tread needs to be completely slick. Any tread pattern will add to unnecessary rolling resistance.

You don't want any protection on the tire sidewalls. This means the low rolling resistance tires can't be ridden on "construction gravel" that consists of large sharp rocks 1-4 cm in size (it will puncture in less than 100 meters there). It can be ridden on gravel roads where the gravel is finer.

It's true that tyre weight affects rolling resistance if it's the weight of the rubber. On the other hand, steel bead tires are heavier than Kevlar bead tires, but the steel bead doesn't add to rolling resistance at all. So when comparing tire weight, note that steel beaded tires are naturally heavier but don't add to rolling resistance. Also wider slightly heavier tire probably has lower rolling resistance than a narrower slightly lighterweight tire, because wider tires have less rolling resistance.

Comment: I have great Conti Ultra Sport I/III on my street bike, but do not think there are similar alternatives for smaller wheels like 16, 20" used on https://www.streetstrider.com/pages/compare for example or even smaller on go karts or tiny bikes like http://a-bike.co.uk/ (?)

Comment: I feel like you are mixing up the words "thread" and "tread" in places. Could you double check, please? For example, I suspect that TPI is **threads** per inch rather than treads per inch, based on the context.

Comment: A study by Michelin showed that for 20"? BMX tires, 60 psi was the optimum. More than that and you start pumping energy into the rider, which can be considered as a damped sdof spring mass for this. Professional cyclists have also stopped using ludicrously thin tires with high pressures.

Comment: Well the question was edited and originally it wasn't about 20" BMX tires. I suspect 6-7 bar on road tires of moderate width is optimum on good roads. On bad roads though ... not so anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess that the lowest rolling resistance tyre should be ultra thin and the highest pressure is correct... IF you are riding on perfectly smooth surfaces.

Velodrome racing cycles where they are racing on polished wood floors can run up to 200 psi or more.  As an extreme example, look at trains where they use hard steel wheels because they are riding on polished steel rails.
But over the past couple of decades, it has become clear that on a rough surface, a very hard wheel and tyre is NOT the best. Even on the best of roads, a very hard tyre will transmit vibration to the rider.  At first this was thought to merely be horribly uncomfortable, but it was then demonstrated that this vibration energy is absorbed in the rider's body, and lost energy means less efficiency.

It is more efficient to have tyres with enough bounce in them to absorb the bumps and elastically give the energy back as you are riding.
To get such an elastic ride, you need tyres that are running at a lower pressure, and wide enough to be able to support your weight at that pressure. You do not want the inflated tyre to collapse so as to impact the rim of the wheel directly, this will cause damage and not be able to elastically return back the energy.

On the other hand, if your tyre is too fat and too low pressure, you'll spend all your energy deforming the big soft tyre, and that will be inefficient too.

The tyre width and pressure to give the best result depends on your weight (bike and rider) and the surface you ride on. The rougher the surface, the fatter and softer the optimum tyre is. It also depends on the material and construction and wall thickness of the tyre.  Modern tyres, at least the high end road tyres, have much thinner and elastic walls, and this means that they can run at larger widths and softer pressures compared with those from decades ago.

The best guess in 2022 is that a tyre of about 30-35mm width is the lowest rolling resistance.  This assumes normal roads and good quality, thin walled, light weight tyres run at 60 psi or so. The actual numbers depend on your own weight, rim width, road surfaces, riding style, the exact model of tyre and probably some other factors.

Comment: Do you know what paragraphs are? Could you please divide your wall of text into paragraphs. I refuse to read this until you do so!

Comment: Nice summary, but sometimes may not be exact(?) for example my favorite Conti Ultra Sport won in rolling resistance tests, running on 23 or 25x700c and it is strange there are also similar favorite mountain version, but they are 2.2" wide and there are about 9 vs 6 bars, anytime you have less, you feel more rolling watts again ;-) In extreme case there is clear dilemma resistance vs comfort. Btw even dead Schwalbe worked fine in higher speeds (there were significant bumps at lower speeds) https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/68435#84555.

Comment: Beware of "rolling resistance tests".  A lot of these are still being run on smooth rollers, which gives a beautiful clean data set, but misses the entire point of needing to deal with bumps and vibration.   Mountain bike tyres are also comparatively thickwalled. Which stops them puncturing on rocks, but means that they suck energy as they flex.